# When publishing app bundle to playstore, do users get reduced download sizes for all the different abi versions like arm, x86,64?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

[I had a look at the documentation here but it doesnt exactly reveal the download policies](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)

So my app uses some external libraries with native code. By analysing the apk and app bundle, my:

1. Universal apk comes to 72 mb
2. Universal app bundle comes to 64 mb
3. x86_64 apk size comes to 29 mb and arm apks are around 20 mb

So my doubt is, when I publish the bundle or universal apk to the playstore, do users download the huge universal builds or device specific builds? I can share my build.gradle if it makes any difference.

Comment: Some additional info: Im using splits{density, abi} as enables so I get different apk builds. I also have minifyEnabled true, shrinkResources true.

Comment: Did you see [About Android App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When We publish the bundle or universal apk to the playstore, Users normally download the device specific builds, If user's device does not lies under any of the category then universal build will be downloaded to the device.

Answer (score 1):

> Google Play uses your app bundle to generate and serve optimized APKs
> for each device configuration, so only the code and resources that are
> needed for a specific device are downloaded to run your app. You no
> longer have to build, sign, and manage multiple APKs to optimize
> support for different devices, and users get smaller, more optimized
> downloads.

[developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

when I publish the bundle or universal apk to the playstore, do users download the huge universal builds or device-specific builds?
Yes

Comment: Oh that was pretty explicit in the documentation. THanks for pointing it out!